# Kibana Server Not Ready

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elk

I configured Elastic search, Kibana and log stash cluster.
Elastic search is working fine, but Kibana is displaying an error stating Kibana Server Not Ready.

Logs shows

```
> x .kibana_task_manager_1."}
Jan 13 12:50:05 kibana-csi kibana[28007]: {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-01-13T12:50:05Z","tags":["info","migrations"],"pid":28007,"message":"Creating index .kibana_1."}
Jan 13 12:50:05 kibana-csi kibana[28007]: {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-01-13T12:50:05Z","tags":["warning","migrations"],"pid":28007,"message":"Unable to connect to Elasticsearch. Error: [resource_already_exists_exception] index [.kibana_task_manager_1/4qj7_j5URN6TW2Pvr5qk7w] already exists, with { index_uuid=\"4qj7_j5URN6TW2Pvr5qk7w\" & index=\".kibana_task_manager_1\" }"}
Jan 13 12:50:05 kibana-csi kibana[28007]: {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-01-13T12:50:05Z","tags":["warning","migrations"],"pid":28007,"message":"Another Kibana instance appears to be migrating the index. Waiting for that migration to complete. If no other Kibana instance is attempting migrations, you can get past this message by deleting index .kibana_task_manager_1 and restarting Kibana."}
Jan 13 12:50:35 kibana-csi kibana[28007]: {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-01-13T12:50:35Z","tags":["warning","migrations"],"pid":28007,"message":"Unable to connect to Elasticsearch. Error: Request Timeout after 30000ms"}
Jan 13 12:50:38 kibana-csi kibana[28007]: {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-01-13T12:50:38Z","tags":["warning","migrations"],"pid":28007,"message":"Unable to connect to Elasticsearch. Error: [resource_already_exists_exception] index [.kibana_1/LDkaYE3JQH2hhq4Xb4uDZw] already exists, with { index_uuid=\"LDkaYE3JQH2hhq4Xb4uDZw\" & index=\".kibana_1\" }"}
```

Need help! 
I aslo tried deleting

`curl -XDELETE 'http://ElasticsarchIP:9200/.kibana_1'  --header "content-type: application/JSON" -u elastic -p`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by the version mismatch between the Elastic Search and Kibana, Use the below versions while Setting up Elastic search and Kibana version matrix documented by the Elastic.co

https://www.elastic.co/support/matrix#matrix_compatibility

Answer (score 6):

First, try deleting the versioned indices and then restart as suggested above:

```
curl -XDELETE http://localhost:9200/.kibana_1
```

systemctl restart Kibana

If it doesn't work then verify you have a versioned index that's been created, e.g. byte counts the same, etc. After that then delete the original .kibana:

```
curl -XDELETE http://localhost:9200/.kibana
```

then alias it:

```
curl -X POST "localhost:9200/_aliases" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d' { "actions" : [ { "add" : { "index" : ".kibana_1", "alias" : ".kibana" } } ] }'
```

Then restart kibana.

Answer (score 3):

I just followed the suggestion that came with the error:

> If no other Kibana instance is attempting migrations, you can get past
>   this message by deleting index .kibana_task_manager_1 and restarting
>   Kibana.

```
curl -XDELETE http://localhost:9200/.kibana_task_manager_1
```

I then restarted Kibana

Answer (score 0):

If you dont care about loosing dashboard/vizu:

```
curl -XDELETE http://localhost:9200/.kibana*
```

This is the only solution, exactly like elasticsearch, **you cant never recover data** without a snapshot.

---

If there is a already `.kibana_1` index, check that `.kibana` alias exists too, or create it:

```
curl -XPUT https://XXXXX/.kibana_1/_alias/.kibana
```

(same thing for task manager index).